# Alternative to Office Web Components

Tags: excel, ms-office, olap, office-web-components

I'm working on an application which is currently using mainly the Excel components
We were upgrading our Office system from 2003 to 2010 and as a result, the part of our application which works with the Office 2003 web component is no longer available.
I'm trying to find equivalent Office 2010 web component with no success
Can anyone help me with this issue??

Answer (score 0):

The [very first result](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/25343a8b-4827-480a-bba3-9a19cfbb4a91) returned by Google searching for "Office 2010 web component" seems to be the answer for your question.
See also [here](http://bit.ly/XU83KU). (I know, I know, it's not up to the standards of SO, but it's the end of the world today, isn't it ?)

Comment: That doesn't even answer OP's question. He looking to upgrade from OWC 11 to something newer. Exact problem I have right now.

Comment: Im also looking for an alternative. This answer is not helpful.

Comment: @armandino: the solution in the link explained there was now new component, and HOW to make 2003 component available for Office 2010 clients. That seems like a pretty valid answer for me, specially since that option was not excluded by the question.